# iOS CoreMIDI Skipping MidiPackets

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, midi, coremidi

I'm having issues with implementing MIDI into my iOS app as the receiver callback seems to be skipping MIDI messages and packets. I'm using [Midi Monitor](https://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/) to check what MIDI messages I'm missing, skipping over, etc.

**So the million dollar question is why is iOS skipping certain MIDI messages?** Sometimes it doesn't skip MIDI messages, but other times it does. I'm not sure how to approach debugging this as I have exhausted my brain at this point.

My receiver code:

```
void MidiReceiver(const MIDIPacketList *packets, 
                  void *context, void *sourceContext) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (packets->numPackets > 0) {
        MIDIPacket *packet = (MIDIPacket *)packets->packet;

        // Loop through total number of packets
        for (int i = 0; i < packets->numPackets; i++) {
            // Go through each packet, iOS sometimes clumps all data into one packet
            // if the MIDI messages are triggered at the same time
            for (int j = 0; j < packet->length; j += 3) {
                NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:packet->data[j]],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:packet->data[j+1]],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:packet->data[j+2]], nil];

                // Use the data to create do meaningful in the app
                [myViewController processMidiData:array];
            }

            // Next packet
            packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet);
        }
    }
});
```

The monitor code format is : (TIME) - (MIDI Command Type) - (CC Val or Velocity)

Midi Monitor Debug:

```
12:45:32.697    Control 0
12:45:32.720    Control 1
12:45:32.737    Control 1
12:45:32.740    Control 2
12:45:32.750    Control 3
12:45:32.763    Note Off    A♯1 0
12:45:32.763    Note Off    F2  0
12:45:32.763    Note Off    D3  0
12:45:32.763    Control 4
12:45:32.770    Control 5
12:45:32.780    Control 6
12:45:32.790    Control 8
12:45:32.800    Control 9
12:45:32.810    Control 11
12:45:32.820    Control 13
12:45:32.832    Control 14
12:45:32.845    Control 16
12:45:32.850    Control 18
12:45:32.873    Control 21
12:45:32.883    Control 22
12:45:32.898    Control 24
12:45:32.913    Control 26
12:45:32.933    Control 27
12:45:32.948    Control 28
12:45:33.020    Control 27
12:45:33.030    Control 26
12:45:33.040    Control 25
12:45:33.050    Control 24
12:45:33.060    Control 22
```

My App's Debug Monitor:

```
12:45:33.050    Control 0
12:45:33.051    Control 1
12:45:33.051    Control 1
12:45:33.051    Control 2
12:45:33.051    Control 3
12:45:33.083    Note Off    D3 0       <----- Where's A#1 and F2!!! :(
12:45:33.087    Control 4
12:45:33.087    Control 4
12:45:33.097    Control 5
12:45:33.100    Control 6
12:45:33.110    Control 8
12:45:33.120    Control 9
12:45:33.130    Control 11
12:45:33.140    Control 13
12:45:33.153    Control 14
12:45:33.165    Control 16
12:45:33.170    Control 18
12:45:33.193    Control 21
12:45:33.203    Control 22
12:45:33.218    Control 24
12:45:33.233    Control 26
12:45:33.256    Control 27
12:45:33.268    Control 28
12:45:33.341    Control 27
12:45:33.351    Control 26
12:45:33.361    Control 25
12:45:33.374    Control 24
12:45:33.381    Control 22
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue but I am not using dispatch_async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some help from [Kurt Revis](https://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/) and it seemed like I was sending the packets too late due to my usage of `dispatch_async`.

My revised code (I parsed the packets first):

```
void MidiReceiver(const MIDIPacketList *packets, 
              void *context, void *sourceContext) {

    NSMutableArray *packetData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (packets->numPackets > 0 && object != nil) {
        MIDIPacket *packet = &packets->packet[0];
        // Loop through total number of packets
        for (int i = 0; i < packets->numPackets; ++i) {
             int idx = 0;
             while (idx < packet->length) {
                 NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:packet->data[idx]],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:packet->data[idx+1]],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:packet->data[idx+2]], nil];

                [packetData addObject:array];
                idx += 3;
             }
             packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet); 
         }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (NSArray *packet in packetData) {
            [object receiveMIDIInput:packet];
        }
    });
}
```